# Objective-C threads and NSZones

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, process

When I first read about NSZone and what it was, I got really excited about the prospect of using zones to isolate threads' memory spaces such that I could effectively kill a thread and dealloc its zone. But it seems NSZone can't really be used for this purpose after all.

So I'm wondering if there's any way to isolate a thread in Objective-C to a particular block of memory that can be killed and dealloced safely?

Failing that, are there ways to spawn child processes (that surely do have their own memory spaces) in Objective-C, similar to how Chrome does things?

Comment: NSZone has been deprecated for a ***long*** time, my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inter-process communication is a subject that is far too challenging for what you're trying to implement.  So long as you're just looking for a representation of some work that you can cancel and deallocate, a subclass of [NSThread](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is perfect.  By overriding `-main`, you can have all the benefits of an NSOperation (not caring exactly *which* thread work occurs on, abstraction from actual threading, encapsulation, etc.), but in a more concrete and cancelable form.

Comment: On OS X processes are either daemons launched through the launchd or other applications.  If the former, you can use either an NSTask, or stick to lower level nasty UNIX things, if the latter, [use XPC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html)